# Data sent via ajax doesn't get written to database

Tags: c#, ajax, httphandler

I'm sending data via ajax to be saved in the formatted and saved in my database. I'm sending the data via a JSON to the HttpHandler which does the work with it.

```
function sendMail() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/MailAction.ashx") %>',
        data: { act: "sendMail", to: $('#<%= txtMailTo.ClientID %>').val(), from: $('#<%= lblUserID.ClientID %>').text(), subject: $('#<%= txtMailSubject.ClientID %>').val(), message: $('#<%= txtMailMessage.ClientID %>').val() },
        success: window.location = "Inbox.aspx"
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, the breakpoint I set on the HttpHandler doesn't seem to be getting hit so I haven't been able to debug the below code, but I don't see any problems with it:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int mailid = 0;
        string action = context.Request["act"];

        MySqlContext db = new MySqlContext();

        string sql = "";
        List<MySqlParameter> args = new List<MySqlParameter>();

        switch (action)
        {
            case "sendMail":
                string to = context.Request["to"];
                int from = int.Parse(context.Request["from"]);
                string subject = context.Request["subject"];

                //
                // FORMAT TEXT FROM MESSAGE BODY
                //
                string message = formatText(context.Request["message"]);

                int userid = 0;
                //
                // GET RECIPIENT ID
                //
                sql = "select userid from users where username = @to";
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@to", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Value = to });

                MySqlDataReader dr = db.getReader(sql, args);

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dr.Read();

                    userid = dr.GetInt32("userid");
                }
                dr.Close();
                args.Clear();

                sql = "insert into mail(sender, recipient, datesent, subject, message, status) values (@me, @you, @date, @sub, @msg, @stat)";
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@me", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32, Value = from });
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@you", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32, Value = to });
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@date", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime, Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") });
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@sub", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Value = subject });
                args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@msg", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Value = message });
                break;
            }

        if (args.Count == 0)
        {
            db.execute(sql);
        }
        else
        {
            db.execute(sql, args);
        }
    }
```

All I can say about what it's doing is that it doesn't insert into the database.

I used the same javascript to pass other values to the handler for other events and all work fine. Mostly those do updates to the database.

Can anyone see if there's any problems with the code here?
It occurs to me that it'd probably be better practice to do this entirely server-side, so if that's a better option then I'm more than willing to give that a go.

Thanks in advance

Comment: not hitting the breakpoint seems strange. Are you able to capture the request and then copy the url into browser and hit it that way and see if the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: or can you copy the request?

Comment: I have Fiddler so can maybe check the request in there if that'll help

Comment: yes please post the request.

Comment: Should probably have mentioned that I don't know how to use Fiddler...

Comment: You can use firefox with [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) too to see what is posted

Comment: Can you update the code for the Http Handler to include the whole class declaration. (I.e. so we can be sure it's extending IHttpHandler...) Since your Ajax call is set to redirect to the inbox page on success, is it successfully doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'success: `window.location = "Inbox.aspx"'`

`window.location = "Inbox.aspx"` is evaluated immediately and the page is switched before any request is made.

Use a function.